# Div Lines in FusionChart XT aren't working in IE11

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, fusioncharts

I am trying to display two charts with FusionChartXT but the div lines don't show up in the second chart in IE.
The first chart is always looking right and on the other chart the div lines disappear.

This is a part of the second chart in Chrome:
[image]

And this is how it looks in IE:

[image]

Is it possible that it won't work because of the html structure?
These are my divs:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This issue was identified in version 3.7. However, with the latest version the seems to be fixed.

{
                "divlineColor" : "#999999",
                "divlineThickness" : "1",
                "divLineIsDashed" : "1",
                "divLineDashLen" : "1",
                "divLineGapLen" : "1",
                "showXAxisLine" : "1",
                "xAxisLineThickness" : "1",
                "xAxisLineColor" : "#999999",
                "showAlternateHGridColor" : "0",

```
        }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fusioncharts/xb9TG/)